# Haskell: Create a list of only certain "kind" of type?

Tags: haskell, types, coding-style

I've been working through both Learn You a Haskell and Beginning Haskell and have come on an interesting problem. To preface, I'm normally a C++ programmer, so forgive me if I have no idea what I'm talking about.

One of the exercises in Beginning Haskell has me create a type Client, which can be a Government organization, Company, or Individual. I decided to try out record syntax for this.

```
data Client = GovOrg { name ::  String }
  | Company { name     :: String,
              id       :: Integer,
              contact  :: String,
              position :: String
            }
  | Individual { fullName :: Person,
                 offers   :: Bool
               }
  deriving Show

data Person = Person { firstName :: String,
                       lastName  :: String,
                       gender    :: Gender
                     }
            deriving Show

data Gender = Male | Female | Unknown
            deriving Show
```

This is used for an exercise where given a list of Clients, I have to find how many of each gender are in the list. I started by filtering to get a list of just Individuals since only they have the Gender type, but my method seems to be completely wrong:

```
listIndividuals :: [Client] -> [Client]
listIndividuals xs = filter (\x -> x == Individual) xs
```

How would I get this functionality where I can check what "kind" of Client something is. Also for the record syntax, how is my coding style? Too inconsistent?

Comment: `x == Individual` - if you come from c++, you should know that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yea, bad thinking on my part. It's like saying `5 == int`. And yet it seems like it isn't because, from my understanding, Individual is a value constructor and not a type. So I guess my question is more of how do I check what value the Client is.

Comment: "how do I check what value the Client is". Pattern matching

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, I would recommend not using record types with algebraic types, because you end up with partial accessor functions.  For example, it is perfectly legal to have the code `position (Individual (Person "John" "Doe" Male) True)`, but it will throw a runtime error.  Instead, consider something more like

```
data GovClient = GovClient {
    govName :: String
    } deriving Show

data CompanyClient = CompanyClient {
    companyName :: String,
    companyID :: Integer,        -- Also, don't overwrite existing names, `id` is built-in function
    companyContact :: String,
    companyPosition :: String
    } deriving Show

data IndividualClient = IndividualClient {
    indvFullName :: Person,
    indvOffers :: Bool
    } deriving Show
```

Then you can have

```
data Client
    = GovOrg GovClient
    | Company CompanyClient
    | Individual IndividualClient
    deriving (Show)
```

Now you can also define your function as

```
isIndividualClient :: Client -> Bool
isIndividualClient (Individual _) = True
isIndividualClient _ = False

listIndividuals :: [Client] -> [IndividualClient]
listIndividuals clients = filter isIndividualClient clients
```

Or the more point-free form of

```
listIndividuals = filter isIndividualClient
```

Here, in order to make the decision I've simply used pattern matching in a separate function to determine which of `Client`'s constructors was used.  Now you get the full power of record and algebraic types, with just a hair more code to worry about, but a lot more safety.  You'll never accidentally call a function expecting a government client on an individual client, for example, because it wouldn't type check, whereas with your current implementation it would be more than possible.

If you're concerned with the longer names, I would recommend eventually looking into the `lens` library that is designed to help you manipulate complex trees of record types with relative ease.

---

With your current implementation, you could also do something pretty similar to the final solution:

```
isIndividualClient :: Client -> Bool
isIndividualClient (Individual _ _) = True
isIndividualClient _ = False

listIndividuals :: [Client] -> [Client]
listIndividuals clients = filter isIndividualClient clients
```

The main difference here is that `Individual` takes two fields, so I have two `_` wildcard matches in the pattern, and the type of `listIndividuals` is now `[Client] -> [Client]`.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I guess I was getting a bit ahead of myself in using the record type in that way.

Comment: @mal20k It's fine to do that if you are _really really_ sure in your API that illegal operations would never be performed, but in general I recommend splitting it out into separate types unified by a single ADT.  Sure, it adds an extra layer of types on top of your records, but you gain a lot of safety and in many cases your types will make a lot more sense.  Even in this small example, the type of `listIndividuals` becomes more expressive about what it is actually doing.  It's these little differences that take experience to spot, so don't be hard on yourself!